# Decode nested JSON objects in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json

I am trying to convert a nested JSON object on an ASP.NET server. The incoming JSON string looks something like this -

```js
data: {
   user_id: 1,
   taskid: "1234",
   list: {
       "item-1": { one: 1, two: 2 },
       "item-2": { one: 1, two: 2 }   
       //.. where number of items is unknown
   }
}
```

I have tried to decode the data using [JSON.Decode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.decode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) this way

```
public class Data {
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string taskid { get; set; }
    public List<object> list { get; set; }
}

public class DataList {
    List<Data> data { get; set; }
}

// if isPost etc..

var decodedData = JSON.Decode<DataList>(Request["data"])
```

But when I try and iterate over decodedData I am getting an error -

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'ASP._Page_that_cshtml.DataList' because
>   'ASP._Page_that_cshtml.DataList' does not contain a public definition
>   for 'GetEnumerator'

When I try casting the decodedData to a List this way -

```
List<Data> decodedData = JSON.Decode<DataList>(Request["data"])
```

I throw another error

> CS0030: Cannot convert type '`ASP._Page_that_cshtml.DataList`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<ASP._Page_that_cshtml.DataList>`'

Could you please suggest an appropriate method to convert nested JSON objects into a C# object and iterating over it?

PS: trailing semi-colons omitted on-purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Data> decodedData = JSON.Decode<DataList>(Request["data"])
```

Should Be

```
var decodedData = JSON.Decode<List<Data>>(Request["data"])
var myDataList = new DataList() { data = decodedData; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating over `decodedData.data` instead.

`decodedData` is a `DataList`, and the `DataList` class has a member `data` which is a `List<Data>`.  `List<Data>` has a `GetEnumerator` method, as required by `foreach`.

Alternatively, you could add a `GetEnumerator` method to `DataList`:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return data.GetEnumerator(); }
```

Comment: Thanks Tim but an error is thrown saying that 'data' is not defined

Comment: @Peter: Try making data public

Comment: Or alternatively, add a method to expose the enumerator (see my edit)

Comment: Thanks but when I add that method to DataList I get - CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>' requires 1 type arguments -  I tried to use IEnumerator<Data> but " System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " on data.GetEnumerator

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not [valid json](http://jsonlint.com/). You should have a collection `[]` for list:

```
data: {
    "user_id": 1,
    "taskid": "1234",
    "list": [
        {
            "one": 1,
            "two": 2
        },
        {
            "one": 1,
            "two": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Actually it is valid JSON using (its stringified to post to the server) - {
    "user_id": 1,
    "taskid": "1234",
    "list": {
        "item-1": {
            "one": 1,
            "two": 2
        },
        "item-2": {
            "one": 1,
            "two": 2
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Peter, I see. OK, the syntax for the collection still looks like it should have square brackets to indicate a collection.

Answer (score 1):

The first error you are getting is quite right, your class `DataList` does not contain a definition for `GetEnumerator` which is required for a foreach statement. You will need to iterate over the property, so iterate over decodedData.data.

The second error is again correct, as you are trying to cast DataList to a type of List, something C# has no idea how to do. You would again need to create your DataList, then set the property data to the type List.

Answer (score 0):

You can try decoding the JSON into an array of Data objects, and then calling the ToList() extension method on that array.

```
var dataArray = JSON.Decode<Data[]>(Request["data"]);
var list = dataArray.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but " System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'ASP._Page_that_cshtml+Data[]'. "

Comment: It might be easier to use the [JSON.net library](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), which provides a very comprehensive set of APIs to work with JSON data. I use it in all of my projects, and I've never had any issues. Also, it is much more performant than the built in C# JSON serlializer. In your case you can use it like this `List<Data> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(Request["data"]);`

Comment: Thanks. But as David Tryon pointed out I am not working with valid JSON and it has a problem with that

Comment: Sure... but if you are going to be working with a lot of JSON data, it would be better to use the JSON.Net library.